# Data structure for compiling postfix expression

Tags: c

Hi I'm writing rpn calculator in C and I'd to compile rpn expression to byte-code.
But I'm not sure what would be the data structure to represent them???
My stack data structure so far is

```
 struct stack_t{
        int type;
        union {  
              double val;
              char *str;
              /* probably some more */
             }u;
    };
```

Comment: Canonical compiler resources question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1669/learning-to-write-a-compiler . Most of the resources listed therein will tell you how to build a general AST, which will certainly do the job, though there might be a simpler choice for your limited domain.

Answer (score 1):

It actually depends a lot on the feature set you are going to support. For example, if your calculator supports integers (e.g., integer division), you probably would need `int` in your union.

Answer (score 0):

The advantage of RPN bytecode is that it doesn't need to be stored in a special structure. An array/vector/list will do. You need a stack to *interpret* it, but to store the program you should only convert each token to a bytecode instruction.

As for what types to put in your union, it really depends on the semantics of your calculator. Why do you want to be able to store strings? Do you plan on using strong typing?

Look into [Forth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forth_(programming_language)), the canonical simple RPN language.

Comment: my guess is that strings may be needed if we'd like to represent variables

Comment: calculator + variables = interpreter

Comment: The calculator so far supports real number and string data type and variables also. Now I'd to add function definition and need to compile the input rather than interpreting on the fly.

Comment: @Nyan: Note that Forth is typically compiled directly to machine code, even on the fly. It's also extensible to allow alternate RPN or even non-RPN syntax. See how fast an implementation of you language in Forth is before you put too much effort into your own.

Answer (score 0):

I've gone through several re-writes of a postscript interpreter, and while my object struct started out exactly like yours, I eventually found this layout to be "better" for reasons that I may not be able to articulate. I found this idea in the X11 Event structure.

```
typedef struct {
    word tag;
    word pad;
    dword padw;
} mark_;

typedef struct {
    word tag;
    word pad;
    integer val;
} int_;

typedef struct {
    word tag;
    word pad;
    real val;
} real_;

typedef struct {
    word tag;
    word sz;
    word ent;
    word off;
} comp_;

typedef union {
    word tag;

    mark_ mark_;
    int_ int_;
    real_ real_;
    comp_ comp_;
} object;
```

It may seem redundant to have the tag both outside and inside each structure, but it keeps everything in nice little boxes. It allows you to *see* the memory layout more clearly.

Edit: I call it "tag" instead of "type" because it contains both *t*ype and fl*ag*s.

---

Edit: One of the reasons I consider this *better* is it eliminates the `.u` term from the access expressions. Instead of `stk.u.val`, you have `stk.real_.val` or `stk.int_.val`. The *union* part is shifted upstream, so the data portions can have internal structure without additional nesting. And the `tag` is still accessible at the top-level to determine which sub-type is being used.